# Second alert not working

Tags: javascript

I have this function which calls values from document id's and some variables are defined.

It all seems to work fine besindes the variables already defined and the second alert box isnt appearing, any idea why?

```
function Calculate() {
var ContentMinutes = document.getElementById ("ContentMinutes").value;
var NoOfFrames = 5;
var EstimatedCoreHours = document.getElementById ("EstimatedCoreHours").value;
var ServiceLevel=document.getElementById('SerivceLevelDD').options[document.getElementById('SerivceLevelDD')    .selectedIndex].value
var RenderHours = 1;
var CoresInTest = 2;

var EstimatedTotal =  GetNumeric(ServiceLevel) * GetNumeric(EstimatedCoreHours);
alert('hi = '+EstimatedTotal.toFixed(2));

var EstimatedCoreHours =  GetNumeric(NoOfFrames) * GetNumeric(RenderHours) * GetNumeric(CoresInTest);
alert(' = '+EstimatedCoreHoursTotal.toFixed(2));
}

function GetNumeric(val) {

if (isNaN(parseFloat(val))) {
return 0;
}
return parseFloat(val);
}
```

---

Sorry I forgot to register...

I commented out the 'var EstimatedCoreHours = document.getElementById ("EstimatedCoreHours").value;' variable as it wasn't needed, Still doesn't work howerver...

Comment: I took the liberty of merging your two accounts and kept the one with the question on it.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
EstimatedCoreHours =
```

but you alert:

```
EstimatedCoreHoursTotal
```

So, I'd guess you want to change:

```
var EstimatedCoreHours =  GetNumeric(NoOfFrames) * GetNumeric(RenderHours) * GetNumeric(CoresInTest);
```

to:

```
var EstimatedCoreHoursTotal =  GetNumeric(NoOfFrames) * GetNumeric(RenderHours) * GetNumeric(CoresInTest);
```